# CoreBluetooth: Can I subscribe a characteristic that has read and write permissions?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I want to connect to a device equipped with **Bluetooth** 4.0 using my iPhone.

I logged the device's (as a **peripheral**) properties: **0x16**. It means

```
CBCharacteristicPropertyRead = 0x02,
CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse = 0x04,
CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify = 0x10,
```

(Suppose I have subscribed this characteristic.) If I write some data to this characteristic , and then its value will be changed, the notify will happen. Obviously, the workflow is not what I want. I just write some data but I don't want get the same data notified call-back.

So, I think **it seems that I shouldn't write anything to what I subscribe**, right ?

Hope for a specific answer.

Comment: is 0x16 the property of `CBPeripheral` or of one of its `CBCharacteristics`?

Comment: 0x16 = 0x02 | 0x04 | 0x10 , which means supporting **read** , **write without response**, and **notify**.

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe for notifications using `setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:` method in [CBPeripheral](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:). Then you will receive notifications via `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` delegate callback whenever the characteristic's value changes.

Note that it's the peripheral that decides when to send notifications:

> Because it is the peripheral that chooses when to send an update, your
> app should be prepared to handle them as long as notifications or
> indications remain enabled

so it's not guaranteed that you will get notified immediately upon writing.